# Application to display battery info

Tags: indicator, battery

First of all, I am not sure the title of this question is the most appropriate however this is what I meant to say,

There are many ways to extend the life of a laptop battery. One way is by not connecting it to the AC adapter all the time which will overcharge it. I read that in this [website](http://www.sony-asia.com/productcontent/364394/productcategory/it-computer-accessories).

1. Is there an application which automatically prevents the charging of the battery once it has reached 80% charged? I mean that is such a cool feature. Sometimes people tend to forget to remove the AC adapter and this could diminish the capacity and reduce the life time of the battery.
2. Does the battery indicator in ubuntu display info or pop-up when the battery is almost dead (dead not in the sense of usage time) but rather a degraded battery?

Comment: I read the opposite from that link. If you keep connecting and disconnecting the battery it will give you less life. Removing it will make you go through more discharge cycles. Check the graphics in your link. What is true is that keeping it at 80% or 50% of the maximum capacity will increase it's live. Note that you can to destroy a battery by letting it get to no charge at all (not where the computer reports 0%, but lower), check the storage instructions on your link.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Wow, that web site is COMPLETELY WRONG.  I am an engineer and among other things, sometimes design and build battery packs.  I have read many data sheets from battery manufacturers and they all say the exact opposite, and I have experimental evidence that they are correct.

Batteries LIKE being fully charged.  If the charger is overcharging them, then it is broken.  A correct charger stops charging the battery when it is full, so it is good to leave it plugged in if you can.  The more often you discharge the battery, and the deeper you do so shorten its life.  A typical battery can handle several thousand cycles if you limit depth of discharge to 30% ( meaning you recharge it once it falls to 70% ).  Going to 50% cuts the life of a typical battery down to the 1000 cycle range, and 30% or less drops it to a few hundred.  A battery that is fully discharged and remains that way for weeks or months will loose much of its capacity if it can be recharged at all.

Notice the inverse relationship between depth of discharge and state of charge.  Battery manufacturers and engineers use the former term.  The marketing guy who wrote that web site probably did not understand the difference and so he got it upside down.

Comment: Wow thanks so much I never knew this, and was always getting wrong info from HP and others.

Comment: great, i practiced full discharging policy and as a result my battery performance has degraded.

Comment: Could you please provide some sources for your claims? I have always seen different information: the higher is the battery charge and temperature the faster the battery loses its capacity. See for example results of my quick search: Sony - [Lithium Ion Rechargeable Batteries Technical Handbook](http://www.sony.com.cn/products/ed/battery/download.pdf) - Long-term storage characteristics graphs on page 23, [Lithium Ion Technical Manual](http://www.tayloredge.com/reference/Batteries/Li-Ion_TechnicalManual.pdf) - Cycle Life Characteristics - Effect of Charging Voltage.

Comment: @pabouk, the second link you mention just says that overcharging the battery shortens its life, which is also well known, which is why you don't do that.  At least every manufacturer spec sheet I have read on lead-acid batteries for 20 years has said that you want to store them fully charged, and top them off every once in a while.  I have adopted the same practice for a laptop with lions I rarely use and in 5 years it hasn't lost any capacity.  I'll see if I can dig up the long term storage specs from our supplier tomorrow, but even so, that's for when you aren't going to use it for months.

Comment: @psusi: excuse me for the delayed reply. In the second link the text is not only about over-charging: "Charging at a slightly lower voltage (4.10 - 4.15 V) will slightly reduce the capacity per cycle – but will increase cycle life because the cell is being stressed less." The full-charge voltage of 4.2 V was selected as a compromise between the capacity and life of the battery. When you cross certain voltage of the battery - the higher the voltage is the ageing of the battery is faster.

Comment: @psusi: Look also here: [How to Prolong Lithium-based Batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries) - mainly Table 4: Discharge cycles and capacity as a function of charge. The website has many useful articles and from what I have read I think they know what they are talking about. ------ Lead-acid batteries and li-ion batteries are different you should not apply the same rules to them in all aspects of them.

Comment: @pabouk, that article agrees with what I have been saying: "a properly functioning Li-ion charger will terminate charge when the battery is full" and '“Should I disconnect my laptop from the power grid when not in use?” many ask. Under normal circumstances this should not be necessary because once the lithium-ion battery is full the charger discontinues charge and only engages when the battery voltage drops. Most users do not remove the AC power and I like to believe that this practice is safe.'.  Further, the product I work on does not even bother doing that and we don't see any degradation.

Comment: @psusi: I noticed that I did not write what I think is wrong in your answer. Excuse me for that. It is this statement: "Batteries LIKE being fully charged." --- I am saying that keeping a li-ion battery at 100 % designed by most of manufacturers (i.e. 4.2 V) makes the life of the battery shorter than keeping it at ~90 % (4.1 V) or even lower. Just see the table 4 and graph 5 in the article I linked last. --- I am not certainly afraid that li-ion chargers will not stop at the designed voltage of 4.2 V. That would be very dangerous to go over 4.3 V with this type of batteries!

Comment: @pabouk, the point of my answer is that chargers generally do *not* maintain a float charge that could damage the battery, and also that despite recommendations from several manufacturers against this, I have not seen any evidence that maintaining a float charge actually does any harm to lithium-polymer cells.  The arguments against doing so for lead-acid are a bit more compelling since the chemistry shows that doing so ionises the electrolyte ( water ), causing them to dry out ( which you can correct with wet cells, but not sealed ones ), but similar chemistry does not exist for lion/lipo.

Answer (score 6):

I don't agree with the answer. Keep battery always 100% charged is NOT suggested.

For Li-Ion rechargeable battery (almost all laptop use li-Ion battery) , most manufacturers suggest to keep them in a cool and dry condition with 40%~50% capacity, no matter for camera battery or laptop battery. Why? Because this is the best conditon for battery storage. I have several evidences to support my opinion:

1) My Thinkpad X31 laptop with battery always full charged and dead in around 3 years later. Only 10% capacity left.

2) My Thinkpad T400 laptop has a battery with good condition after 3 years usage (more than 85% capacity left), by limitting the threshold to 30%~80%. I never overcharge or deep discharge the battery, it will reduce the lifespan of battery significantly.

3) I have several 18650 size Lion Sanyo batteries, which is the material of laptop battery, when they were shipped to me, the voltage are all around 3.78V (around 40% of it's capacity), while the full charged voltage is 4.20V. It means in factory, they are charged only to 40% capacity, for storage reason.

I saved them for around 2.5 years in refrigerator (so it's always cool), and the voltage of them still keeps around 3.76V~3.77V.

Answer (score 4):

- You can get some additional information, apart from right clicking the battery icon next to the clock (get's shown when you pull out your power chord), by opening a Terminal and typing

  ```
  cat /proc/acpi/battery/BAT1/*
  ```
- > Does the battery indicator in ubuntu display info or pop-up when the battery is almost dead (dead not in the sense of usage time) but rather a degraded battery?

  Yes it does:

  [image]
  (something like that)

Comment: In case anybody's wondering: Yes this is an old screen shot, but I have actually seen this message — it's just hard to replicate.  :)

Answer (score 2):

OMG, The top answer is wrong and it is very convincing since its first paragraph.

However, when it comes to "Batteries LIKE being fully charged", it is clear that there is some miXunderstanding between Li-ion and other batteries (Ni-based and lead-acid).

Ni-based and lead-acid car batteries "LIKE being fully charged" but Li-ion "DO NOT".

It is already correct that Li-ion LIKEs being in 30%-80% level of charge due to Li-ion cell deterioration beyond the range.

However, the answer were already right about depth of discharge i.e. the less discharge the more life cycle.

I used to have the same conclusion as the top answer when I first read that top search-result [How to Prolong Lithium-based Batteries](http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/how_to_prolong_lithium_based_batteries) page and remembered only the part about depth of discharge. Years after I got to read it again and was so dazzled how could I missed to remember such critical part so I did search for Li-ion cell deterioration and found a research paper so I was certain it was true about 30-80% myth.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Congratualtions on a good first answer!

Comment: Thanks. 5 more reputation so I can vote the above answer.