# Apps that can control the charge/discharge of batteries

Tags: 11.04, software-recommendation

I will like to know the Pros and Cons of any program out there that automatically stops the charging of laptop batteries at certain percentage levels.

Comment: why would you want a program to stop charging at a certain percentage?  Seems strange that you dont want a battery to be fully charged.

Comment: well the laptop is always plugged in and read it might the battery life

Comment: Yes, if you leave the computer connected for long periods of time can really ruin the battery. I would suggest unplugging the battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer covers your question

[How to charge the battery till 60-80% only?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22268/how-to-charge-the-battery-till-60-80-only)

Program to manage battery charge:

[management application](https://launchpad.net/~opensource-subakutty/+archive/ppa/+files/aircraft-manager_12.1_i386.deb)