# Is there a way to run the laptop only on AC power without removing the battery?

Tags: laptop, power-management, battery

Is there a way possible to run a laptop only on AC power without having the need to remove the battery  i.e. to disable the charging as it is possible in Windows 7.

Comment: Just a note, Windows 7 does not have the option to disable battery input, nor does it have the option to disable charging reliably.

Comment: http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/forums/20/absolute-beginners/350358/running-laptop-without-battery/

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/233315/is-it-safe-to-operate-a-laptop-without-battery

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way this is possible would be on a hardware level. I've never heard of a laptop that had this as an option, though.

In Windows that is probably done by a driver for this purpose. Something like Smart Battery in DELL laptops. Not sure if that will be an option for your laptop, check the builder's website.

Comment: I needed a solution for this because my battery life is going down so i want to save it from degrading further due to over charging.

Comment: You just remove the battery. There is no other solution.

Answer (score 0):

According to [How to charge the battery till 60-80% only?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22268/how-to-charge-the-battery-till-60-80-only/22272#22272), you can use Dell's Airplane manager to enable airplane mode so now the laptop will not charge the buttery and run off AC power instead.

You can install it from [ppa:opensource-subakutty/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~opensource-subakutty/+archive/ubuntu/ppa), but personally I couldn't manage to install it on a 64-bit Trusty machine.